# Math.toDegree() in kotlin gives unexpected results

Tags: java, kotlin, trigonometry

When I calculate cos 579.894 (in degrees) in google calculator it gives -0.76723232005 (the answer I want).

When I do this in Kotlin, `Math.toDegrees(Math.cos(579.894))`, it gives the answer: `-15.291167290241946`

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5):

In mathematics and programming, trigonometric functions like cos typically expect angles to be in radians, not degrees. In your case, when you used Math.cos(579.894), you were providing an angle in radians, which resulted in the incorrect answer.

To fix this, you should convert your angle from degrees to radians before passing it to the Math.cos function. Here's how you can do it in Kotlin:

```
import kotlin.math.cos
import kotlin.math.toRadians

fun main(){
    val degrees = 579.894
    val radians = Math.toRadians(degrees)
    val result = cos(radians)
    println(result)
}
```

Java :

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double degrees = 579.894;
        double radians = Math.toRadians(degrees);
        double result = Math.cos(radians);
        System.out.println(result);
    }
}
```